# Run a bash script over network

Tags: 14.04, server, scripts, ssh, lan

I have a LAN which contains more than 50 ubuntu machines. 
I want to change entire LAN authorization with a centralized ldap server.
I have a working LAN server, and i wrote a script to do all the client side configurations.

I don't want to SSH to each system and run the script. So is there anything i can do for running the script on the entire LAN simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSSH should do the job.
All you need to do is supply a known_hosts file and the script:

```
pssh -h host-file --user -P ./script
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical for a small amount of machines, something along the lines of below would work fine.

```
ssh user@192.168.1.11 'uptime'
```

To access all a larger group of servers, you could wrap it it a for loop such as below. Or

```
$SERVERS = server1 server2 server3

for SERVER in $SERVERS
    do  
    ssh user@$SERVER 'uptime' 
    done
```

Now for something as big as 50 servers you may want to start diving into Puppet (https://puppetlabs.com) or  ANSIBLE ( https://www.ansible.com ). There is also SALT and CHEF. See this [article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2609482/data-center/data-center-review-puppet-vs-chef-vs-ansible-vs-salt.html) for a decent comparison between them.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't got you. I don't want to ssh to each and every machine.

Comment: it's a one time configuration. That's why i am not considering puppet. And can you please elaborate what you meant by 'uptime'?

Comment: Uptime (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/uptime.1.html ) is merely an example of something to run over a lot of servers. You may want to have a read only test when running a command on this many servers. Also, this may not be the only time you ever have to administer these 50 machines. Why not develop an infrastructure for future maintenance  and care of the machines? I've already up-voted the other`pssh` answer. If you're looking for a one-off, try that one. Ansible/Puppet would be along term solution.